# How to upload a file in blazor SSR .net 8?

Tags: c#, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I created an EditForm with Model and Enhance properties, when submit to the server by OnValidSubmit="Submit" the break point works in Visual Studio but IFormFile field of ViewModel is null in break point. How to resolve?

Comment: It's great you self-answered, but the question still needs to be understandable and answerable by others. Please add a [mre] to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
I resolved by 2 changes:

1. Adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to the EditForm tag.
2. Adding name="vm.PdfFile" to the InputFile tag.

<EditForm Model="@vm" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="CommodityAddEdit"
          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" Enhance>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="vm.Title" class="form-control" placeholder autofocus />
        <label>Title</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => vm.Title" class="text-danger" />
        @if (ShowAlert == true)
        {
            <Alert Text="@AlertText" />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputFile name="vm.PdfFile" class="form-control" placeholder />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => vm.PdfFile" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success w-50">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>


[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private AddCommodityVm vm { get; set; } = new();

public async Task Submit(EditContext editContext)
{
  // break point and watch editContext
}

public class AddCommodityVm
{
    [Required, Length(2, 50, ErrorMessage = Constants.LengthMsg)]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    public IFormFile? PdfFile { get; set; }
}
```